# Show that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} b \cdot (1-\sqrt{3})^n=0 \quad \forall b \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I want to show the following limit:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} b \cdot (1-\sqrt{3})^n=0 \quad \forall b \in \mathbb{R}
$$

It makes sense that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(1-\sqrt{3})^n=0$ since $|1-\sqrt{3}|<1$ and so $b \cdot \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (1-\sqrt{3})^n=b \cdot 0$.

But how do I then show:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-\sqrt{3})^n=0
$$

Comment: You have already mentioned $|1-\sqrt{3}|<1$ and this implies that $(1-\sqrt {3})^n\to 0$. There is nothing more to show.

Comment: This depends on what you have know and have already proven.  Have you proven if $\lim a_n = A$ then $\lim c*a_n = c*A$.  That's something that should be proven *once* and then refered to with impunity.  Have you proven that for all $|a| < 1$ then $\lim a^n = 0$?  If so you are done.  If not, is that your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you would like to see that

- $0< |q| < 1 \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} q^n = 0$

A possible way to see this is as follows:

- Note that $|q^n| = |q|^n$
- $0< |q| < 1 \Rightarrow 0 < |q|^{n+1} < |q|^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
- $\Rightarrow $ it exists $ L =\lim_{n \to \infty} |q|^n $ and $L \geq 0$

So, it is enough to show that $L = 0$:
$$|q|^{n+1} = |q| \cdot |q|^{n} \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} L = |q|L \Rightarrow L(1-|q|) = 0 \stackrel{1-|q|>0}{\Rightarrow} L = 0$$